# Sum of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n}(x-3)^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I don't know the rate of questions on this site but it feels like I'm bombarding you folks with questions.
But anyways, the problem I'm struggling with is:

If $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n}(x-3)^n}{n!}$, what is $f^{(5)}(3)$?

I know that this is a taylor series centered at $x=3$, but I don't know how to approach this problem. I'm mainly stuck by that $\sqrt{n}$ in the summand.

Comment: Do you mean $f^{(5)}(3)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'll fix it right now.

Comment: Can you see from the general Taylor formula that $
f^{(n)} (3) = ( - 1)^n \sqrt n $?

Comment: What would be the answer, if the series "would be" instead a final sum going till -say- $n=9$... ?

Comment: Recall that in a power series $f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n(z-z_0)^n$, $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}$

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you, it finally clicked for me i got it

Comment: @Gary I see that now, the answer would be $(-1)^5\sqrt{5}$

Comment: @Aquackic Yes, that is correct (note that $(-1)^5 =-1$).